# How to find second last index number in foreach Method

Tags: javascript

My problem is common but rare case,My Output of array  is

```
#0 :  [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
#1 :  [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
#2 :  [ 'v', 'h', 'f' ]
#3 :  [ 'd', 'y', 'z' ]
#4 :  [ 'k', 'q', 'f' ]
```

How to find this type array second last index number is 3 ?

```
forEach(response, ',', function(row, index) 
              {
               console.log('#' + index + ' : ', row);
                console.log(index.length)//undefined
})
```

Comment: Is it indexed array or associative?

Comment: an array has an `length` property - does that guide you to the answer?

Comment: indexed array output code is above

Comment: index.length property is undefined.

Comment: What you are trying to find? value in the second last index?

Comment: `index` is the not an array. It is the index of the current element being processed in the array. It doesn't have length property

Comment: then how to find second last index number

Comment: If the name of your array is `response` you can use `response.length - 2` to get second last index number

Comment: @HassanImam its common answer , my array structure is xml to csv converted array,and then comma separated for each..      and reposnse length is 16000. but my last index number is 160

Comment: It appears that you have a sparse array, you can use the below command to access your 2nd last element `var res = myArray.filter(function(e, i, a) { return e != undefined;}); console.log(res[res.length - 2])`

Answer (score 0):

If your array is indexed, then as simple as:

```js
var myArray = [[], [], [], [], []];
console.log(myArray.length - 2);
```

If it's object:

```js
var myArray = {0: [], 3: [], 6: [], 9:[]};
var indexes = [];

for (var i in myArray) {
  indexes.push(i);
}

console.log(indexes[indexes.length - 2]);
```

Comment: my question is not common type array. comma separated each string and assign to index,,  please remove this answer